# How do I use an external method that returns a promise? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, plugins, bluetooth, ionic2, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to JavaScript and didn't understand how to properly use Promises.

I'm calling a function from a native plugin from ionic 2 (BLE): `IsEnabled()` it reports if bluetooth is enabled on the device, it returns a promise that resolves if bluetooth is enabled. I tried different approaches but they aren't working:

In BLEscanner.js

```
      blEnabled() {
       BLE.isEnabled();
       return Promise;
      }
```

In Home.js

```
    var BLicon {
     iconColor = function () {
       if (BLEscanner.blEnabled().Promise.isFulfilled())
        return '#606060'; //the icon displayed is gray

       else return '#030303';
     };
     msg = function () {
      if (BLEscanner.blEnabled().Promise.isFulfilled())
        return "Bluetooth is ON";

      else return "Bluetooth is OFF";
      }
    }
```

I'm gonna use the `msg` in an action alert when the icon will be typed. But I'm not sure how to use/develop the `isFulfilled()` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLE.isEnabled() returns a promise:

```
 blEnabled() {
       return BLE.isEnabled();//Returns a promise
 }
```

In Home.js you can use it in this way

```
BLEscanner.blEnabled().then(() => {
    //success
    iconColor = '#606060';
    msg = "Bluetooth is ON";
}, () =>{
    //fail
    iconColor = '#030303';
    msg = "Bluetooth is OFF";
});
```